# How to Custom cake bake in cakephp 2.x

Tags: cakephp, customization, cakephp-bake

I'm new in cakephp.
And I try the amazing feature in this framework, cake bake
I want to customize output in the model, view and controller in cake bake

1. How to create new file view in baking (view,index,add,edit .ctp) example export_excel.ctp
2. How to display schema field, in example folder ("C:\xampp\htdocs\cake\lib\Cake\Console\Templates\default\actions\controller_actions") for modified controller output. like "lib\Cake\Console\Templates\default\views\index.ctp" i found this script:

```
foreach ($fields as $field): //but this code i put in the controller_task not working
```

Sorry for bad post, my english is bad..

Answer (score 0):

Question 1 - Do want to be able to create a custom view type using bake? I guess you could extend CakePHP's bake shell, something like this (app/Console/Command/MyBakeShell.php):

```
App::uses('AppShell', 'Console/Command');
App::uses('BakeShell', 'Console/Command');

class MyBakeShell extends BakeShell {
public function startup() {
        parent::startup();
    }

    // Etc etc, your implementation here...in the main() method I guess you could add a call to new function for generating your custom view
}
```

Is that what you're after? I Imagine this would be quite fiddly, you may have a use case that justifies the work though.

Question 2 - Didn't really understand this?

Comment: thanks for reply, i will try. Sorry for question 2, I can't write in english well. Essentially such displays listings schema fields in the table, in the template model/controller ('lib\Cake\Console\Templates\default\classes\'). such as display field in the template view / index / form ('lib\Cake\Console\Templates\default\views'). I tried the "foreach ($ fields as $ field):" but it can only be for the template view/index /form

Comment: Thanks for reply, I had updated my question, I hope you better understand. Sorry for my confusing question

Answer (score 0):

being a novice myself, I hope I can help you.

When you bake, it creates for you all the model, controller and view.
I discovered that by answering the questions about the fields, relationships in tables and helpers it creates all these for you, I suggest you create a mysql db with 2 tables and make relationship between the 2 and start to bake and do this several times to see what things are happening [reading cakephp manual] will help as well of course.

When you understand the relationship between the mvc then you will know you can create your own controller and a view to  build extra pages for example.

I had some trouble to understand the plural and others till I found this url about the inflector, I can advice this to you as well. http://inflector.cakephp.org/

If you want to create a new view, you need to create first a new controller.
Then create a folder and put in that folder your new view index.ctp

So let's say you want to create a new page on your website called spain, create controller spain manual in folder app/Controller/SpainController.php

```
 <?php
 App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
 /**
 * Spain Controller
 *
 */
 class SpainController extends AppController {
public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

public function index() {
$this->set('title_for_layout', 'Properties in Spain');
 }
 }
 ?>
```

Then you create your view in /app/View/Spain/index.ctp

```
 <!-- View for Spain -->
 <br /><h1 align="center">Put your text here...</h1><br />
 <div align="center"><hr><br />
```

That's it regards your own view...
Not sure if I understand you correct about this export.excel but it seems to me you want to create something what exports data out of your DB. So you start cake bake, 1 controller, select the tables with the data to export and answer the questions. When whole process done, you can modify your view.

Not sure about your other question.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I had updated my question, I hope you better understand. Sorry for my confusing question

Answer (score 0):

copy paste lib/Cake/console/template  to  templates/your_name/views/3files

modify 3 files bake to see changes